# Updating multiple records of a binary file c++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm having trouble for updating multiple records of a binary file records within a single reading of a file.

Where one record can be updated for a single reading, while updating more than one record, the program runs in an 
infinity loop.

The first code works fine, but the problem with the second code:

The First Code:

```
for (i = 0; i < xcnt; i++)  {
    fseek (ptr_fsecfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(fread(&temp2, sizeof(temp2), 1, ptr_fsecfile)) 
        if (strcmp(temp2.SecName,xncmplst[i].SecName)==0) {
           xncmplst[i].SecCode = temp2.SecCode;
           xncmplst[i].CompId  = 100 * temp2.SecCode + temp2.SecCount +1;
           temp2.SecCount += 1;
           fseek (ptr_fsecfile, - sizeof(temp2), SEEK_CUR);
           fwrite(&temp2, sizeof(temp2), 1, ptr_fsecfile); 
           FlushFileBuffers(ptr_fsecfile);
           break;
        }
};
```

The Second Code:

```
fseek (ptr_fsecfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
while(fread(&temp2, sizeof(temp2), 1, ptr_fsecfile)) 
    for (i = 0; i < xcnt; i++)  
        if (strcmp(temp2.SecName,xncmplst[i].SecName)==0) {
           xncmplst[i].SecCode = temp2.SecCode;
           xncmplst[i].CompId  = 100 * temp2.SecCode + temp2.SecCount +1;
           temp2.SecCount += 1;
           fseek (ptr_fsecfile, - sizeof(temp2), SEEK_CUR);
           fwrite(&temp2, sizeof(temp2), 1, ptr_fsecfile); 
           break;
        };
FlushFileBuffers(ptr_fsecfile);
```

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: `fread` should not immediately follow `fwrite` without an intervening `fflush` or `fseek`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine.